# Will medical institutions reject an applicant based on being 28 years of age?

Tags: graduate-admissions, medicine

As I've contemplated the future over the past year, I have returned over and over again to the idea of becoming a doctor -- specifically, a neurosurgeon. However, I recognize that as a 28 year old Physics BS who would need to take a year of postbac courses before even applying to medical school, I might face unreasonable challenges should I choose to pursue this goal. I recognize that by the time I would be ready to apply, I would be 7 to 8 years older than the typical medical school applicant. My main fear is the idea of getting partway down the road to becoming a doctor and then being unanimously rejected by the institutions (schools, residency programs, employers, etc.) based on my age, rendering my efforts fruitless. Is this a likely outcome?

Comment: In the US, at least, it would probably be illegal to discriminate against you based on age.

Comment: @Buffy Not probably. Definitely. I can't believe people keep posting these kinds of questions.

Comment: I briefly had a job working for a medical school, and part of the onboarding training involved a scenario with a 60-year-old applicant. The training very explicitly said that considering age or dropping hints like "residency is very demanding" was 100% illegal.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning Other countries train doctors & neurosurgeons... And they accept the « older » student... A friend had his BEng Hons then changed to medicine - he found sorting all the mixing of chemicals %vol, %mass so easy, in fact all the others went to him for help - partly because the lecturer was useless...

Comment: @Buffy actually, in the US the Age Discrimination in Employment Act makes illegal to discriminate against *people older then 40* based on their age (https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/age.cfm), so unless your particular state has some extra laws against that (some of them do) it would be perfectly legal to have hiring policies that discriminate against 28-year olds based on their age.

Comment: Most medical students end up following a different specialty than they expect https://www.ama-assn.org/residents-students/specialty-profiles/specialty-preferences-and-after-med-school-numbers You also might turn out to be a bad surgeon - surgeons are dextrous athletes, unless you've been doing neurosurgery you don't know if you're any good at it yet. That's okay, but be careful of being too focused, it's probably a much bigger issue than your age.

Comment: I chose neurosurgery because it seems to make sense for me: I have always enjoyed dextrous performance tasks from Rubik’s cubes to eSports to guitar playing to typing.

Comment: (And, to some extent, excelled at them)

Comment: @DJG That's fine, and it's fine to think of as a goal, but be ready to go another direction. Don't go to med school unless you'd be okay with another specialty.

Comment: If I was rejected as a neurosurgeon, would I be able to gracefully pivot and be a neuroscientist instead?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: they post them because there is also the real world, where your age counts. Being 28 can be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on the position. If there are quantifiable entrance indicators (say, an exam result) then obviously age cannot count. If you have three candidates and someone's age is outside the norm it is better to know. I once applied for a job and was told to come back in 10 years, despite having all what was needed for the position. I was just too young (as they put it: "not enough gray hair")

Comment: @DJG Neuroscience is a basic science discipline, not a medical one. The two main schools of medicine are Neurology and Neurosurgery. There is overlap, but neurologists do more diagnosing of brain, spine, and peripheral nervous system problems including neurodegenerative disease and dementia; neurosurgeons operate on brains in cases of trauma, vascular issues like stroke, and cancer.

Comment: @Peteris The applicable law for med school applications and residency is the [Age Discrimination Act of 1975](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/frontpage/faq/age.html), which prohibits discrimination without regard to age group. All 50 states have age discrimination laws, many of which also prohibit discrimination without regard to age group in employment as well.

Comment: @DJG There's always neurology residency. For neuroscience, that's probably a more feasible career path than neurosurgery (broad overgeneralization, obviously!).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the US, being 28, 30, or even 40 is not a problem for getting into med school. I was 26 when I was admitted, and I was far from the oldest in my class. In fact, by my senior year, they had admitted a couple of students older than my current age at the time! If you haven't been slacking off in between college and now, it could make you even more competitive because you can point to past successes and have interesting stories for the interviewing process. A typical medical school in the US could easily fill each class with biology and chemistry students fresh out of college with high GPA's and MCAT scores. Someone older might have all of those, plus the strengths of a rigorous career or valuable experience outside of medicine. You can differentiate yourself from the rest of the pool.

Now, to the main issue of age. By the time you finish the pre-reqs, ace the MCATs, and finish 4 grueling years of medical school, do you think you'll have the energy or motivation to do an even more intense additional 7 years of neurosurgery? Neurosurgery is competitive enough that they can pick whatever candidate they want. While not a given, you will likely face some "soft" age discrimination for intense/competitive residencies and fellowships. For this stage, you'll have to work extra hard to convince them you can physically compete with the youngin's, much less complete/survive the program. Once you finish your neurosurg training, you won't have problems finding a job. Once you're board eligible/certified, no hospital cares what school you went to, how old you are (to a point), or what you did in the past. All that matters is what you can do for them, ie increase billing by a zillion dollars.

You can get more detailed responses and support from the forums.studentdoctor.net website. There's even a sub-forum for the "non-traditional" applicant, which honestly, isn't so non-traditional anymore!

Comment: "Couple of students older than my current age" would be more informative if we knew what your current age is

Comment: @Moyli He said he started med school at 26, so by senior year, he was 30.

Comment: I actually did a combined MD/PhD program, so I was actually 34 (eek!) by the time I graduated!

Answer (score 6):

Being a few years older is definitely *not* a problem for entering medical school.

I know people who have gone off and done other professions before figuring out that they actually wanted to be a doctor.  The difference between being 20 and being 30 just isn't that much, and you even may have an advantage in some ways from having more maturity and a better understanding of why you want to be in the profession.

Comment: I taught Calculus somewhere with a well regarded postbac premed program, and they had a great placement rate and plenty of the students were in their late 20s.  This really isn't unusual at all.